# How to call a panel in swing

Tags: java

I Create a frame and in that frame I put one panel n I made a tabbed pane also. I placed 4 icons in the main panel..and I create many panels out side that frame but in the same package. I just want when I click one of the button then it will display the panel out side that class with in the tabbed pane.

```
Frame
    Pakage
        Main screen(Where tab pane and buttons are present)
        Panel1.java
        Panel2.java
        Panel3
```

I just want to know how to call `Panel1.java` inside tab pane. I am Using NetBean.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I'm sure I don't understand the question. Code?

Comment: To call a panel you have to create a method that calls a dialog.

Comment: Could you please post your code so I can have a look

Comment: See [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add the panels created in the panel classes to your tabbedPane inside your main class.

You will need to instantiate the Panel1, Panel2 object etc in your pane to then add them, such as:

```
public static void main(String[] argv){
JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabPane.add(new Panel1());
tabPane.add(new Panel2());
}
```

But seeing your code would be helpful to fully understand your problem.

EDIT: 
To do this in response to a button press, check out this tutorial on Action Listeners:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html